# this recursive expression is less or equal to zero at some point?

Tags: recursion, continued-fractions

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ where $N \geq 3$, $r \in \left(\frac{2N}{N+2},2\right]$ and $p-1 \in \left(1,\frac{N+2}{N-2}\right)$. Define for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$ recursively the expressions:
$$\frac{1}{t_1}=\frac{1}{r}-\frac{2}{N}>0,$$
where the expression above is positive by assumption,
and
$$\frac{1}{t_j}=\frac{p-1}{t_{j-1}}-\frac{2}{N}. $$

My question is: There exist some $j_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{p-1}{t_{j_0}}-\frac{2}{N} \leq 0\,\,?$$

I've tried to find some pattern for $t_j$, but the expressions get very complex very fast. Any hint on how to proceed to decide if such $j_0$ exists will be very helpful, thank you.

For the context of the problem, this question arised when deciding if an bootstrap argument for the regularization of an elliptic PDE is a finite process.

Comment: For $r=2$ and $N=3$, $\frac1{t_1}<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac1{t_j}\right)$ follows a (first order) [linear recurrence with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients#Conversion_to_homogeneous_form) hence you may easily find [its closed form](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suite_arithm%C3%A9tico-g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trique#Cas_o%C3%B9_a_%E2%89%A0_1) and deduce its sign.